# Drive service API some parameters not working

Tags: node.js, google-api-nodejs-client

The title says it all, `fields` and `q` don't work for some reason.
In my Drive, I have a folder called "Imprensa", which `fatherId` corresponds to, inside this folder I have more folders, these beign used as category per folder (e.g.: news, article, informative, etc).
The query is suposed to get these folders, folders that have as parent the "father" (Imprensa), but instead it brings up everything that is contained within my Drive.
I just copied the quickstart from [Google Drive APIs Rest docs for node](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/nodejs#step_3_set_up_the_sample), so basicly, the code is the same from there.

**Drive API v3**

**googleapis v26.0.1**

```
var fs = require('fs');
var readline = require('readline');
var google = require('googleapis');
var googleAuth = require('google-auth-library');

// If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials
// at ~/.credentials/drive-nodejs-quickstart.json
var SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly'];
var TOKEN_DIR = (process.env.HOME || process.env.HOMEPATH ||
    process.env.USERPROFILE) + '/.credentials/';
var TOKEN_PATH = TOKEN_DIR + 'drive-nodejs-quickstart.json';

// Load client secrets from a local file.
fs.readFile('client_secret.json', function processClientSecrets(err, content) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('Error loading client secret file: ' + err);
        return;
    }
    // Authorize a client with the loaded credentials, then call the
    // Drive API.
    authorize(JSON.parse(content), listFiles);
});

function authorize(credentials, callback) {
    var clientSecret = credentials.installed.client_secret;
    var clientId = credentials.installed.client_id;
    var redirectUrl = credentials.installed.redirect_uris[0];
    var auth = new googleAuth();
    var oauth2Client = new auth.OAuth2(clientId, clientSecret, redirectUrl);

    // Check if we have previously stored a token.
    fs.readFile(TOKEN_PATH, function (err, token) {
        if (err) {
            getNewToken(oauth2Client, callback);
        } else {
            try {
                oauth2Client.credentials = JSON.parse(token);
            } catch (error) {
                console.log('error: ', error);
            }
            callback(oauth2Client);
        }
    });
}

function getNewToken(oauth2Client, callback) {

    var authUrl = oauth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
        access_type: 'offline',
        scope: SCOPES
    });
    console.log('Authorize this app by visiting this url: ', authUrl);
    var rl = readline.createInterface({
        input: process.stdin,
        output: process.stdout
    });
    rl.question('Enter the code from that page here: ', function (code) {
        rl.close();
        oauth2Client.getToken(code, function (err, token) {
            if (err) {
                console.log('Error while trying to retrieve access token', err);
                return;
            }
            oauth2Client.credentials = token;
            storeToken(token);
            callback(oauth2Client);
        });
    });
}

function storeToken(token) {
    try {
        fs.mkdirSync(TOKEN_DIR);
    } catch (err) {
        if (err.code != 'EEXIST') {
            throw err;
        }
    }
    fs.writeFile(TOKEN_PATH, JSON.stringify(token));
    console.log('Token stored to ' + TOKEN_PATH);
}

function listFiles(auth) {
    var service = google.google.drive('v3');
    const fatherId = '15buNwg19v6u9tY4AuJBjmy1q1ySdiRo4';

    service.files.list({
        auth: auth,
        // 'orderBy': 'modifiedTime desc',
        fields: 'nextPageToken, files(id, name)',
        q: `'${fatherId}' in parents`
    }, function (err, response) {
        var folders = response.files;
        console.log('folders: ', folders);        
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this modification?

#### From :

```
q: `parents in '${fatherId}'`
```

#### To :

```
q: `'${fatherId}' in parents`
```

#### Note :

- This supposes that you can already retrieve the access token.

#### Reference :

- [Search for Files](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/query-ref#examples)

If this was not useful for your situation, I'm sorry.

### Edit :

It was found that the reason of this issue was due to the version of googleapis. When v26 is used, the issue occurs. When googleapis is downgraded to v24, no issue occurs.

Comment: It s no use, I've tried. It may be a bug.
I've read the docs and searched something related to this, but no luck.

Comment: @Rick Stanley I'm sorry for the inconvenience. Can I ask you about the error messages?

Comment: There's actually no error message whatsoever, the query returns everything in my Drive, from the very beginning.
I've update my question to clarify this part.

Comment: And another thing is, is that other parameters like `fields`, simply don't work.

Comment: @Rick Stanley In order to confirm the situation of your issue, can you show us your current script?

Comment: There you go. Just a side note, I've switched to PHP, so it's not urgent, but in case there's a clarification about this, some people will be glad.

Comment: @Rick Stanley Thank you for updating your answer. What version of googleapis are you using?

Comment: @Rick Stanley When I changed the version of googleapis, I confirmed the same situation with you. I think that the reason may be due to the version of googleapis. Can you try to do by downgraded to v24 of googleapis? When I use v24, the script works fine. When at v26, the same situation occurs.

Comment: @Rick Stanley This workaround was useful for your environment?

Comment: Yes, it was, although I would like to use the current version and keep up-to-date with it, it works. Some updated docs would be nice too.

Comment: @Rick Stanley Thank you for your reply. By recent update of googleapis, some errors are confirmed. I think that this may be one of them. I believe that this will be modified in the near future. I updated my answer. Can you accept this? Other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question which can be solved.

Comment: @Rick Stanley Thank you for your response.